# Graduate school applications with papers in the peer review process

Tags: graduate-admissions, research-undergraduate

I am currently applying for graduate school and I have research papers that are currently in the peer-review process. What is the best way to send the schools these papers, since in the application forms, there does not seem to be a section to highlight the journals where I submitted my papers? They do not allow submissions like arXiv.

Comment: _They do not allow submissions like arXiv._ — Who doesn't?  The journals?

Answer (score 3):

There must be space to highlight why are you interested in this school? or briefly describe your research interests.

In any of the above space. you can highlight your submitted papers something like:
I have submitted this work to this journal which is now in under review.

You can also append the abstracts along with co-authors and Journal of each submitted papers to your CV at the end.